# Why have colors suddenly become dark and saturated in Gtk3 features & applications on my GNOME system?

Tags: gnome, themes, desktop-environments, colors, gtk3

I've tried to search through the forums to find out why my folder/files icons became darker, why my font is different than how it was before and why many system applications are very saturated in color (nautilus, terminal, document viewer etc.). I've tested many workarounds without luck.

**EDIT:** The pattern I see here is that GNOME applications are affected and all applications that relies on GTK3 since I am using the adapta-gtk-theme, though I'm not sure if this is related in any way.

I am using **Lenovo thinkpad T460s** with Ubuntu 16.04 running with GNOME desktop environment and having Lenovo Skyland integrated graphic card (Intel driver).

How can I fix this?

Before:

[image: Here is a picture before]

After:

[image: Here is a picture after]

Comment: What did you do before this happened?

Comment: Looks like you've made some kind of theme related changes. Given that we know nothing about your system, and zero info is provided, the question is unclear, vague, too broad.

Comment: That is a theme you changed (icons are different too).

Comment: @Rinzwind THe icons are the same, just different ordering.

Comment: Looks like the color/gamma settings were messed with.

Comment: It looks like the text isn't anti-aliased in the second screenshot (i.e. the text is "jaggy", compared to the first pic). Did you do something with your graphics driver?

Comment: @mikewhatever I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS with gnome desktop manager and adapta theme.

Comment: @George I had normal system upgrade and went smoothly. I didn't do anything else.

Comment: @VanessaDeagan the setting of antialiassing is **rgba** and I didn't touch any of the system configuration or the drivers.

Comment: Dears, I think my problem is with gtk3.20 compatibility with some applications. I don't know what is the exact problem, but I was trying to downgrade to gtk3.18 but things would be complicated and doesn't want to mess up my system.

Comment: @jaywad Take this to Ubuntu forums, Ask Ubuntu people are just too proud to suggest better places for a question. You will need to do troubleshooting so we give a hint: theme change, driver configuration or driver issue. Research on your system in this areas and go to Ubuntu forums.

Comment: @jaywad Similar problem solved for me with an update today (several mesa related libraries were updated, I don't know if there is a cause -> effect link).

Comment: @Lgen Many thanks for your comment. It worked for me as well with an update just now for some mesa related libraries, adapta-gtk-theme and xserver-xorg-core etc.

Comment: Were you using any PPAs for your graphics drivers?

Comment: @edwinksl Thanks for your question. Actually I am using two PPA's and here they are (1) http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu (2) http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu.

Can you help which one should I keep knowing that the update of the mesa libraries are coming from the first PPA?

Comment: Keep the second PPA but use `ppa-purge` to remove the first one and downgrade your Mesa drivers to the ones in the Ubuntu repositories (https://askubuntu.com/q/307/15003) and then restart your computer to see if it helps. I was using the Padoka PPA (https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa) and purging it fixes the problem.

Comment: I am now using the stable version of the Padoka PPA (https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa) instead and it doesn't cause the "color problem". You can try using this PPA too, but only after using `ppa-purge` on the Oibaf PPA just to confirm that purging works.

Comment: Thanks @edwinksl. Honestly, I am not going to risk it at the moment since I really need my laptop fully functional :D. However, I will try it at later stage and/or if the problem comes again later.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. `ppa-purge` is pretty safe though. On the rare occasions that it has failed on me, `sudo apt install -f` fixes the weird edge cases. Let me know when you decide to try.