# (Unity desktop) My applications became darker for unknown reason

Tags: unity, gnome, 17.04, brightness

My display freezed and I had to forcefully restart my laptop. I restarted with „systemctl kexec” through SSH.

Since then, my applications are rendered darker than usual for no apparent reason. Not all applications are affected. For example, Firefox, LibreOffice are not affected. GNOME Terminal, System Monitor, Calculator, GEdit are affected, however. The pattern I see here is that GNOME applications are affected, though I'm not sure if this is the key.

[image: Darker applications]

See the attached screenshot. It is well visible that my applications are rendered darker than other desktop components: the Unity taskbar and the global title bar are rendered with their normal brightness, while the applications are noticeably darker. The purple background of the GNOME Terminal is almost like black. What might be the reason and how could I fix it?

I use Unity desktop on Ubuntu 17.04.

Might be related to this other question, though it doesn't have enough details to tell:
[Why my Ubuntu colors became dark?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958741/why-my-ubuntu-colors-became-dark)

Comment: Have you done a normal full reboot yet?

Comment: Yes, reboot does not help.

Comment: @MegaBrutal Also this question https://askubuntu.com/q/964659/478343 (I asked) seems to be related (no solution so far however).

Comment: @MegaBrutal Problem solved for me with an update today (several mesa related libraries were updated, I don't know if there is a cause -> effect link).

Comment: Are you using any PPAs for your graphics drivers?

Comment: @edwinksl Yes, oibaf. I'm considering to remove it to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Use `ppa-purge` to remove it and downgrade your graphics drivers to the ones in the Ubuntu repositories (https://askubuntu.com/q/307/15003) and restart your computer to see if it helps. I was using the Padoka PPA (https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa) and purging it fixes the problem. I am now using the stable version of the Padoka PPA (https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa/) instead and it doesn't cause the "color problem". You can try using this PPA too, but only after using `ppa-purge` on the Oibaf PPA just to confirm that purging works.

Comment: @MegaBrutal I use the same ppa (ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers). After updating yesterday the dark colors disappeared for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem was solved for me with a full-upgrade. Some mesa related libraries, adapta-gtk-theme and xserver-xorg-core were updated with some additional libraries.