# Strange colours in Ubuntu since October 12, 2017

Tags: 16.04, colors

Yesterday I installed updates as normal and colours became strange. The menus are very dark as are window title bars and text in the terminal is almost unreadable. Everything else seems fine.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know what happened or how I can fix it?

I haven't installed anything new for ages.

Comment: Were you using any PPAs for your graphics drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is just a theme change. Try changing theme under settings to any light theme.

Comment: I haven't changed themes... it has nothing to do with themes I think. After a closer look all colours seem darker / have more contrast - and adjusting brightness does nothing. This person has a similar problem 21 days ago: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958741/why-my-ubuntu-colors-became-dark

Comment: @riscos3 Problem solved for me with an update today (several mesa related libraries were updated, I don't know if there is a cause -> effect link).

Comment: hmmm. i dont get any update :( i use intel hd 520 integrated.