# Evince color problem

Tags: colors, evince

I have a problem with color rendering in Evince (3.18.2) in Ubuntu 16.04: the colors are darker than normal since a few days. Below a picture that shows a pdf file rendering in Okular on the left (correct) and in Evince on the right (too dark).

[image: Okular vs Evince]

Is there a way to tune or to reset the color scheme of Evince ?

EDIT: I have the same problem with EyeOfGnome when opening image file. May be the problem relates to gnome. Still trying to find an explanation.

EDIT2: The problem seems related to gnome apps and several users seem to try to solve it (such as [(Unity desktop) My applications became darker for unknown reason](https://askubuntu.com/q/961762/478343) or [Why have colors suddenly become dark and saturated in Gtk3 features & applications on my GNOME system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/958741/478343)).

Comment: Did you customize it? Try to rename `~/.config/evince` folder.

Comment: @Redbob: I did not customize evince directly and it is the only application with this change of colors. I tried to remove `~/.config/evince` folder and also to remove/reinstall evince but with no luck.

Comment: I think you activated the "evince night mode" with f7 or f9 key, not sure what key is... try disabling it in the menu bar

Comment: @RenatoA. Thanks but I can't see such a "night mode" in Evince. There is a "inverted colors" menu item but changing this does not solve the problem (it literally invert colors).

Comment: @Lgen this happens too in shotwell

Comment: Problem solved with an update today (several mesa related libraries were updated, I don't know if there is a cause -> effect link).

Comment: Are you using any PPAs for your graphics drivers?

Comment: @edwinksl: Yes, I use the following ppa (ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers) and the updated packages (such as libgles2-mesa:amd64, libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64...) were updated from this ppa. I hadn't linked the problem with the ppa but it seems directly related. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Use `ppa-purge` to remove it and downgrade your graphics drivers to the ones in the Ubuntu repositories (https://askubuntu.com/q/307/15003) and restart your computer to see if it helps. I was using the Padoka PPA (https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa), which uses some packages from the Oibaf PPA, and purging it fixes the problem.

Comment: I am now using the stable version of the Padoka PPA (https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa) instead and it doesn't cause the "color problem". You can try using this PPA too, but only after using `ppa-purge` on the Oibaf PPA just to confirm that purging works.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar colour change with menus, titlebars and terminal windows. I asked a question about it just now, but maybe it is the same cause?

[Strange colours in Ubuntu since 12.10.2017](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964655/strange-colours-in-ubuntu-since-12-10-2017)

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem is the same since I only have a change in color scheme in pdf rendering. All other elements (menus, titlebar, terminal...) remain correct.